# PrimeVue Dropdown access country code from #value template to set default selected flag

Tags: vue.js, dropdown, primevue

I have a Dropdown in a student edit modal, and need to show a flag for the default country. In `PrimeVue` the country code can be accessed from a template with `#option="slotProps"`, but not with `#value="slotProps"`. In that case i can only access the name of the country, and it will show the name of the country but not the flag. The `slotProps.value.code?.toLowerCase()` will be empty because there is no `code` but only an object with a `value` which is the country name and a `placeholder` that says `select a country`. And somehow i need to access the country code in order for the flag image to show.

```
    <div :class="flexBetweenCenter" class="mb-3 p-2">
      <label for="placeOfBirth">Place of birth</label>

      <Dropdown
        id="placeOfBirth"
        :options="countries"
        filter
        placeholder="Select a Country"
        v-model="user.placeOfBirth"
        optionLabel="name" 
      >
        <template #value="slotProps">
          <div v-if="slotProps.value" :class="flexAllignCenter">
            <img
              :alt="slotProps.value.label"
              src="https://primefaces.org/cdn/primevue/images/flag/flag_placeholder.png"
              :class="`me-2 flag flag-${slotProps.value.code?.toLowerCase()}`"
              style="width: 18px"
            />
            <div>{{ slotProps.value }}</div>
          </div>
          <span v-else>
            {{ slotProps.placeholder }}
          </span>
        </template>
        <template #option="slotProps">
          <div :class="flexAllignCenter">
            <img
              :alt="slotProps.option.label"
              src="https://primefaces.org/cdn/primevue/images/flag/flag_placeholder.png"
              :class="`me-2 flag flag-${slotProps.option.code?.toLowerCase()}`"
              style="width: 18px"
            />
            <div>{{ slotProps.option.name }}</div>
          </div>
        </template>
      </Dropdown>
```

Comment: You don't have enough details, what are you talking about by "student edit model" ? It is just a custom component from you ? Share the code of this component, as well, share the code of the composition api script where you handle your variables

Answer (score 0):

Check this example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/j8jihs?file=src%2FApp.vue

Your code seems to work fine provided that you have correct format for `countries` data.

```
countries: [
  { name: "United States", code: "US" },
  { name: "Canada", code: "CA" },
],
```

[Screenshot of working example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1PNr.png)

Comment: It works when you select a country, but its a student edit modal so student will already be having a country set (default) and that's what i'm talking about, it will show the name of the country but not the flag because the class name need country code, such as ```:class="`me-2 flag flag-DE`"```, ```user.placeOfBirth``` will hold a value like ```Germany``` (as stored in database), it seems that i need to store the object itself in the database in order for ```v-model``` default value to work